# single select query for multiple retrieving records according to parameters present or absent

Tags: sql-server

I am passing some parameters to a search function.I want to a single query which returns all records if these parameters are empty, and returns those records that match these parameters if they are present.

Answer (score 1):

A condition like...

```
Where ISNULL(@Param1,Field1)=Field1 and ISNULL(@Param2,Field2)=Field2
```

Comment: I am passing some values to the search function and if these values are empty i want to dsiplay all the records,but even 1 value is present i have to display the respective record